# preventing format change due to gsub()

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a data.frame called dataframe and I want to replace all zeros with Hs. I did it with gsub and it works well but there is a "format change" when I call up the replaced dataframe. I want dataframe to look like a data.frame (if you know what I mean)

```
dataframe
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     c1    c2    c3
* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    78    89    56
2    89    89     0
3     0    34     4
> gsub("0","H",dataframe)
[1] "c(78, 89, H)"  "c(89, 89, 34)" "c(56, H, 4)"  
> dataframe <- gsub("0","H",dataframe)
> dataframe
[1] "c(78, 89, H)"  "c(89, 89, 34)" "c(56, H, 4)"
```

How can I replace something (with gsub) without changing the appearance of dataframe (like in the [1] below). `str_replace()`or `apply()` trials change the format,too ;(

Thank you for your kind help

Comment: You can use `rapply()` with `how = "replace"` or you can use `lapply()` with something like this: `dataframe[] <- lapply(dataframe, function(x) gsub("0", "H", x, fixed = T)`

Comment: yes,@Andrew you are right. I haven´t abstracted my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **have** to use `gsub`, you could `unlist` and maintain the original dimension with `[]`.

```
dataframe[] <- gsub("0","H",unlist(dataframe))
dataframe

#  c1 c2 c3
#1 78 89 56
#2 89 89  H
#3  H 34  4
```

However, wouldn't this be simpler?

```
dataframe[dataframe == 0] <- 'H'
```

**data**

```
dataframe <- structure(list(c1 = c(78L, 89L, 0L), c2 = c(89L, 89L, 34L), 
c3 = c(56L, 0L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```